# How do I initialize a hsql in memory DB with populated logback tables

Tags: hsqldb, logback

I am trying to setup a DBAppender with Logback to point to HSQL, but logback needs 3 tables to run.

Logback appender:

```
<appender name="data-db" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
  <connectionSource class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
    <driverClass>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driverClass>
    <url>jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.</url>
    <user>sa</user>
    <password></password>
  </connectionSource>
</appender>
```

Is there a way of passing or getting HSQL to pick up the script when logback is be initialized? I am able to do this as part of a Java app, but when I try it from logback it creates an empty DB

Comment: You must use `<driverClass>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driverClass>` for HSQLDB. Also why do you use an in-memory database instead of a file database?

Comment: Sorry I was switching between the two. I did have the config right when I was running it. I am using in memory as I need quick assess to the the data and I don't want it persisted.

Comment: A memory database has no tables when it starts. You need to execute the statements to create the tables.

Comment: Yes I know, but I am creating it within my logback conf before the application starts. I am not sure if can I point it to a file within the URL to execute the SQL